# General jquery function for form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small tabbed system developed in PHP/JavaScript.

For form submissioni, I bind a JQuery function to the 'submit' event that sends an Ajax query to the server, avoiding to reload the page (and losing other tabs). I have coded one function for every form, but realized that they are the same (take the inputs, send the Ajax query, show the returning message) so I decided to make a general jquery function with arguments that define each form).

I have this function:

```
function submit_search(entity){
        $('#'+entity.name+'_searchform').submit(function(){
            var url = public_path+entity.name+'/search';
            var key = $('#'+entity.name+'_search_key').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: {search_key: key},
                success: entity.submit_search(result)
            }); 

            return false;
    });
}
```

Where `entity` is a JS object with the name of the entity and the success function I want to execute. This function is written in a script that loads once when the main page is loaded. And when the tab is loaded, I simply call `submit_search()` with the actual entity.

This seems logical to me. But it doesn't work. And the problem is that jquery doesn't recognize the elements, by example, after `var key = $('#'+entity.name+'_search_key').val();`, key is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're writing this correctly: `$('#'+entity.name+'_search_key').val();`. Are you sure that `entity.name` contains the correct value that you expect?

Comment: yes @swatkins, it has the correct value, just printed an alert(entity.name) and it is OK

Comment: Are you also sure that that points to something like an text input (that has a `val()`) with an `id` and not just `name` that matches what you're looking for.

Comment: What value is being passed to "entity"?  Are you sure that "'#'+entity.name+'_search_key'" exists?  You can use developer tools on chrome or ie (F12) and put a linebreak on this function and see what is being passed in. Then check to see if $('#'+entity.name+'_search_key').length is greater than one (meaning it does exist).

Comment: yes, @MattWhipple, as I said, it was working before I decided to make the 'general function', when I had one function for each form. They were basically the same function, but with hard-coded values

Comment: matt has a good point - if ..._search_key is a div, you might have to use .html() instead of .val()

Comment: where are you checking `key` that it is returning the wrong result?  Are you breaking or logging immediately after it is being assigned?

Comment: @Losbear $('#'+entity.name+'_search_key') is a text input

Comment: @MattWhipple just after the initialization, with an alert. If I do it the old way, the alert shows the right value.

Comment: but a breakpoint there and check your assumptions using the console.  You can use the `debugger` command to create a programmatic breakpoint if you don't want to fish through the source using tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success function will be executed before request

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {search_key: key},
            success: *entity.submit_search(result)*
        })
```

I suppose submit_search doesn't return a pointer to a function so
you need to pass the pointer to submit_search

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {search_key: key},
            success: *entity.submit_search*
        })
```

And about reconginzing the elements - be sure that you wrote correct selector. Try to hardcode expected experssion in browser's debug/watch tool and check if it's ok, like

```
$('#EntityNameValue_search_key').length > 0
```

Comment: submit_search is a function. But haven't got to the point to check if it works or not. My problem is that I can't access $('#entityname_search_key') I don't know why :(

Comment: Could you provide an example of form and it's content? Especially an input you want to access. And note that when you are within submit event hadler this keyword is the form - try `$(this).find('input')` or something like this

Comment: You were right about submit_search function. The pointer must be passed. And there was the problem, I thought it was lines before. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to abstract all of this in a re-usable way you could use something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", "form.ajax", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        var successFunk = $target.attr("data-success") || "success";
        var url = $target.attr("action");
        $.post(url, $target.serializeObject(), {
            success: function(data) {
                window[successFunk](data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

serializeObject is available here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject

Then you'd just create a form like:

```
<form class="ajax" action="url_i_want_to_post_to" data-success="successCallabck">
  <input type="text" name="search_key"/>
</form>
```

Which would post a JSON object of `{search_key: ${value_of_search_key}}` to the form's destination and call the function `successCallback` or whatever you specify on return.  Ideally you'd want to scope your callbacks better instead of latching on to `window`. You could use a registry, but otherwise using an object named something like FORM_CALLBACKS would keep things organized.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't something like this work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_form').live("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do some magic
    });
});
```

You wouldn need to mix some manual functions with jquery code then.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Not sure of what you suggest. My form name is entity.name+"_searchform", by example: city_searchform, country_searchform